# Conversion from html to org-mode error: *** Eval error *** Wrong type argument: listp, " "

Tags: org-mode, debugging

I tried to build a small converter which will traverse the dom-tree and output its org-mode equivalent but I faced a `*** Eval error ***  Wrong type argument: listp, "     "` error means the list is an empty string or a non-closed quote is being captured.
How can i improve on this if possible and fix the error?
The purpose of the function is to return an org-mode headings and subheadings from the tags obtained the dom-node which should be in a format of

```
*~div~ text-from-dom-node-if-exists
  :PROPERTIES
   list-of-dom-attributes
**~p~ text-from-dom-node-if-exists
```

I'm open to any suggestions.

```
(defun org-tagify-node (node depth)
  "Convert a DOM NODE into Org-mode text with appropriate depth."
  (let* ((tag-name (dom-tag node))
         (text (and (stringp tag-name) (dom-text node)))
         (attributes (dom-attributes node))
         (attr-text (if attributes
                        (concat ":PROPERTIES\n"
                                (mapconcat (lambda (attr)
                                             (format "  - %s: %s" (car attr) (cdr attr)))
                                           attributes
                                           "\n")
                        "")))
         (stars (make-string depth ?*)))
    (concat stars "~" tag-name "~"
            (if text (concat " `" text "`") "")
            "\n" attr-text
            (mapconcat (lambda (child)
                         (org-tagify-node child (1+ depth)))
                       (dom-children node)
                       ""))))


(defun macro-etagify (tag-entries)
  "Return the Org-mode representation of HTML tags."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert tag-entries)
    (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max))))
      (org-tagify-node (car (dom-by-tag mytags 'body)) 1))))

let ((myskel "<html>
     <head>
         <title>Demo: Gradient Slide</title>
     <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans\" rel=\"stylesheet\">
     <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"dist/build.css\">
     </head>
     <body>
         <header data-table=\"testtable\">
             <h1 data-field=\"testfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
             <h1 data-field=\"newfield\">Skeleton Screen</h1>
         </header>
         <div class=\"wrap\"> Sample Text <p class=\"format\" data-attribute=\"somethingsomething\">Welcome to this page</p>
             <div class=\"flex-grid generic-card\">
                 <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE -->
                 <div class=\"card loading\">Text </div>
                 <!-- ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIMATE 
                   this multiline comment 
                    -->
                <div class=\"card loading\"></div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>"))
```

From the debugger, I have the following

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp "\n         ")
  dom-tag("\n         ")
  (let* ((tag-name (dom-tag node)) (text (and (stringp tag-name) (dom-text node))) (attributes (dom-attributes node)) (attr-text (if attributes (concat ":PROPERTIES\n" (mapconcat (lambda (attr) (format "  - %s: %s" ... ...)) attributes "\n") ""))) (stars (make-string depth 42))) (concat stars "~" tag-name "~" (if text (concat " `" text "`") "") "\n" attr-text (mapconcat (lambda (child) (org-tagify-node child (1+ depth))) (dom-children node) "")))
  org-tagify-node("\n         " 2)
  (closure ((stars . "*") (attr-text) (attributes) (text) (tag-name . body) (depth . 1) (node body nil "\n         " (header ((data-table . "testtable")) (h1 ((data-field . "testfield")) "Skeleton Screen") "\n             " (h1 ((data-field . "newfield")) "Skeleton Screen") "\n         ") (div ((class . "wrap")) " Sample Text " (p ((class . "format") (data-attribute . "somethingsomething")) "Welcome to this page") "\n             " (div ((class . "flex-grid generic-card")) "\n                 " (comment nil " ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIM...") "\n                 " (div (...) "Text ") "\n                 " (comment nil " ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIM...") "\n                " (div (...)) "\n             ") "\n         ") "\n     ") t) (child) (org-tagify-node child (1+ depth)))("\n         ")
  mapconcat((closure ((stars . "*") (attr-text) (attributes) (text) (tag-name . body) (depth . 1) (node body nil "\n         " (header ((data-table . "testtable")) (h1 ((data-field . "testfield")) "Skeleton Screen") "\n             " (h1 ((data-field . "newfield")) "Skeleton Screen") "\n         ") (div ((class . "wrap")) " Sample Text " (p ((class . "format") (data-attribute . "somethingsomething")) "Welcome to this page") "\n             " (div ((class . "flex-grid generic-card")) "\n                 " (comment nil " ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIM...") "\n                 " (div (...) "Text ") "\n                 " (comment nil " ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIM...") "\n                " (div (...)) "\n             ") "\n         ") "\n     ") t) (child) (org-tagify-node child (1+ depth))) ("\n         " (header ((data-table . "testtable")) (h1 ((data-field . "testfield")) "Skeleton Screen") "\n             " (h1 ((data-field . "newfield")) "Skeleton Screen") "\n         ") (div ((class . "wrap")) " Sample Text " (p ((class . "format") (data-attribute . "somethingsomething")) "Welcome to this page") "\n             " (div ((class . "flex-grid generic-card")) "\n                 " (comment nil " ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIM...") "\n                 " (div ((class . "card loading")) "Text ") "\n                 " (comment nil " ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIM...") "\n                " (div ((class . "card loading"))) "\n             ") "\n         ") "\n     ") "")
  (concat stars "~" tag-name "~" (if text (concat " `" text "`") "") "\n" attr-text (mapconcat (lambda (child) (org-tagify-node child (1+ depth))) (dom-children node) ""))
  (let* ((tag-name (dom-tag node)) (text (and (stringp tag-name) (dom-text node))) (attributes (dom-attributes node)) (attr-text (if attributes (concat ":PROPERTIES\n" (mapconcat (lambda (attr) (format "  - %s: %s" ... ...)) attributes "\n") ""))) (stars (make-string depth 42))) (concat stars "~" tag-name "~" (if text (concat " `" text "`") "") "\n" attr-text (mapconcat (lambda (child) (org-tagify-node child (1+ depth))) (dom-children node) "")))
  org-tagify-node((body nil "\n         " (header ((data-table . "testtable")) (h1 ((data-field . "testfield")) "Skeleton Screen") "\n             " (h1 ((data-field . "newfield")) "Skeleton Screen") "\n         ") (div ((class . "wrap")) " Sample Text " (p ((class . "format") (data-attribute . "somethingsomething")) "Welcome to this page") "\n             " (div ((class . "flex-grid generic-card")) "\n                 " (comment nil " ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIM...") "\n                 " (div ((class . "card loading")) "Text ") "\n                 " (comment nil " ADD .loading CLASS TO ANY ELEMENT TO SHIMMER/ANIM...") "\n                " (div ((class . "card loading"))) "\n             ") "\n         ") "\n     ") 1)
  (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max)))) (org-tagify-node (car (dom-by-tag mytags 'body)) 1))
  (progn (insert tag-entries) (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max)))) (org-tagify-node (car (dom-by-tag mytags 'body)) 1)))
  (unwind-protect (progn (insert tag-entries) (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max)))) (org-tagify-node (car (dom-by-tag mytags 'body)) 1))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer)))
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert tag-entries) (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max)))) (org-tagify-node (car (dom-by-tag mytags 'body)) 1))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))
  (with-current-buffer temp-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (insert tag-entries) (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max)))) (org-tagify-node (car (dom-by-tag mytags 'body)) 1))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))
  (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*" t))) (with-current-buffer temp-buffer (unwind-protect (progn (insert tag-entries) (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region ... ...))) (org-tagify-node (car (dom-by-tag mytags ...)) 1))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer)))))
  (with-temp-buffer (insert tag-entries) (let* ((mytags (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max)))) (org-tagify-node (car (dom-by-tag mytags 'body)) 1)))
  macro-etagify("<html>\n     <head>\n         <title>Demo: Gradient ...")
  (let ((myskel "<html>\n     <head>\n         <title>Demo: Gradient ...")) (macro-etagify myskel))
  eval((let ((myskel "<html>\n     <head>\n         <title>Demo: Gradient ...")) (macro-etagify myskel)) t)
  ielm-eval-input(#("(let ((myskel \"<html>\n     <head>\n         <title>..." 0 1 (fontified t) 1 4 (face font-lock-keyword-face fontified t) 4 14 (fontified t) 14 1003 (face font-lock-string-face fontified t) 1003 1031 (fontified t) 1031 1032 (fontified t rear-nonsticky t)) nil)
  ielm-send-input(nil)
  ielm-return()
  lispy-newline-and-indent-plain()
  funcall-interactively(lispy-newline-and-indent-plain)
  command-execute(lispy-newline-and-indent-plain)
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Can you please add the expression that you are trying to evaluate in `ielm`? The debugger elided most of it: ` (let ((myskel \"<html>\n     <head>\n         <title>...` so wec can't see what you typed and we can't see how you called `org-tagify-node`. But that is crucial information, without which all that can be said is what @Drew has said in his answer. Please edit the question and *add* that information to it.

Comment: I have added it earlier, it has been edited. let me add it again,

Comment: @NickD, I've added it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that function `dom-tag` expects a list and it's being passed a string.

Evidently you're passing a string to `org-tagify-node`, which passes it to `dom-tag`. Either you need to pass `org-tagify-node` a list or `org-tagify-node` needs to first obtain a list from the string you're passing it, and then pass that list to `dom-tag`.

Comment: Can you please share some snippets?

Comment: Dunno what you mean. `org-tagify-node` is your code, no? I have no idea what code defines `dom-tag`. I'm just explaining that your code is passing a string to a function that requires/expects a list. It's up to you to figure out what list to pass it, to get the behavior you want.

Comment: it's rather `org-tagify-node` I renamed the function to `dom-tag` to help in debugging.

Comment: I have updated the code, can you look at it ?

Comment: The children of a node are not necessarily nodes: they can be strings, so when `org-tagify-node` is called recursively on the first child of the body, it gets a string as argument and gives you the error. You will either need to filter out such strings before you call `org-tagify-node` recursively (and also at top level obviously, its caller (`macro-etagify` in this case) would also have to enforce that restriction); or you would have to make `org-tagify-node` smarter and able to deal with strings as well.